# Problemas con los SRC en una pagina HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5

probando mi aplicación me he dado cuenta que en firefox - mozilla los `input type='date'` no funcionan, buscando un poco en la red encontré una solución  con datepicker que en una pagina de pruebas funciona genial!

Mi problema es que en varias paginas debo tener acceso a exportar en excel  y cuando coloco todos los src me genera algún tipo de conflicto que no permite que funcione alguno de los dos .. el que quede mas abajo ..

Como puedo solucionar esto ??
Este es el codigo que me genera conflicto:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
        <!--  Librerias para datepicker  -->          
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
          <script src="JS/datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!--Exportar Excel-->       
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="JS/exportarExcel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Entiendo la cuestión de las versiones de jquery, pero si coloco la mas reciente no me funciona ninguno de los 2 ... que puedo hacer '?

## EDICION

Cuando abro el codigo para ver que problema se presenta , me muestra esto,

> > TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function[Saber más]  datepicker.js:8:11
> >     El uso de getPreventDefault() está desaprobado. Use en su lugar defaultPrevented.  jquery-1.9.1.js:3346:28
> >     [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas advertencias varían si quito alguno de los 2 src .. o el de datepicker o  el de exportar excel .

## EDICION 2

este es el codigo de `datePicker.jsp`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var es_firefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;

          if (es_firefox ) {
          $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#datePicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
          $("#datePicker2").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
          });
          }
});
```

Comment: que error recibes en la consola?

Comment: No se presente error en pantalla  , edite la pregunta para mostrar mas detalles de cuando miro el código en el navegador.

Comment: Estás importando 2 versiones diferentes de jQuery, puede que eso esté generando conflicto.

Comment: Elimina la linea `<script src="JS/datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: Si, entiendo esa parte, pero si no importo esas versiones o no funciona exportar excel o no funciona el datePicker...  si conocen una forma de que las 2 cosas funcionen seria grandioso en este momento .

Comment: @Hictus en ese .js tengo este codigo:
$(document).ready(function() {
var es_firefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;

          if (es_firefox ) {
          $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#datePicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
          $("#datePicker2").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
          });
          }
});

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente, el problema se presenta por incompatibilidad  de versiones.

La solución es subir la versión de `datePicker de 1.9 -> 1.10` para que no genere problemas.

```
<title>Reportes Equipo</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!--Librerias para Exportar --> 
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="JS/exportarExcel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

          <!--Librerias para datepicker-->            
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
          <script src="JS/datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede que tu problema venga de que estas haciendo

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#datePicker").datepicker({
     dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
}).val();
```

Estas invocando el método `.val()` antes de la inicialización del componente. Prueba a quitar el `.val()` de ambos datepickers.

**EDICION**

Con respecto a las versiones de jquery duplicadas, quédate con la mas actual, y ten en cuenta, que la declaración de las archivos `js` deben llevar un orden lógico, es decir, primero importa las librerías de `jquery`, luego las de `jquery-ui` y por ultimo las tuyas propias.

Comment: Modifique la pregunta para que veas el código utilizado. @Hictus

Comment: Entiendo pues, que todos tus problemas son solo en firefox?

Comment: Si, mi aplicativo funciona bien en Chroom , pero firefox no permite el input  type ='date' por lo cual requiero el datepicker....  ya que se realizan varias validaciones por rango de fechas.

Comment: Trabaja con Internet Explorer y cambiaras ese dicho

Comment: @Andres Felipe Diaz haciendo las cosas que te he puesto no te funciona?

Comment: @JackNavaRow compatibilidad hasta version 8 de IE por necesidades de cliente. Cada mañana que vengo a trabajar, rezo porque Windows haya erradicado ese error engendrado... sin exito claro :)